# Query set of number of related objects

Tags: python, django, object, django-queryset

I have model A with a fk to model B

Now I need to make a queryset that gets all B's with less then 5 A's linked to them.

*Edit* Maybe I should have mentioned this is a Django project and what I'm looking for is a Queryset reference thats efficient enough to be run quite a number of times

i've tried something like:

B.objects.select_related()

but I don't understand how to limit this qs to only include the B's with max 5 occurrences

Comment: Okay, good luck (i.e. what have you tried? what's the problem? where's your code?)

Comment: You were right, Clicked confirm by accident nice -1 within a minute of posting, editted it now sadly can't put up any actual source code

Comment: @nopogo: Take a moment to read http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/rubber-duck-problem-solving.html. Don't be in such a rush to ask a question. Take time to thoroughly evaluate what you're trying to achieve, what you've tried, etc., and re-read your question before posting. You wouldn't have got a downvote if you had done that.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Thanks for the heads up and the link, will try that method from now on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use annotations:

```
from django.db.models import Count

B.objects.annotate(a_count=Count('a')).filter(a_count__lt=5)
```

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/

Answer (score 0):

Your question it's not very clear but how I understand it I think the code you need is these one:

```
from django.db.models import Count
b_qs = B.objects.annotate(num_a=Count('authors')).filter(num_a__lt=5)
```